# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for React, Axios

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to test how to use Axios to send data to a PHP file, and I keep running into this error. I've tried looking up the answers online, but I can't really parse through most of them. The basic outline of the react code is below.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios({
           method: 'post',
           url: 'http://localhost/my-app/src/api/test.php',
           data: {
                title: this.state.title,
                ...,
                data7: this.state.data7
            }
        });
        alert('Data submitted!')
}
```

And I tried to keep the PHP code equally basic.

```
<?php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo $_POST[title];
?>
```

Is the problem that I need to add more things to my PHP file, or do I need to set things up with my React code to make the localhost acceptable for PHP? I've tried things like disabling web security for chrome and using `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`, but I just can't figure out what causes this error, and I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: use a normal variable to affect your data instead of $_POST the use var_dump instead of echo

Comment: Do you have a webserver running on port 80 ? default http port is 80, if your webserver is using a different port (must be because you are in development) `http://localhost:*PORTNUMBER*/*URI*`

Comment: I changed it to the proper port number (3000), now it's giving me a 404 error because I don't have the proper URI. What should be the first directory in it? The react app directory, src, api?

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` can in fact be the result of *almost any* sort of "connection error."  Despite the name, it does **not** mean that "the remote host recognized you, identified you, and then 'refused' to speak with you."